# node js service in docker stops, but works if not dockerized

Tags: node.js, docker

i have built a simple api using typescript and node. it works when i run this service locally like that:

`node --experimental-specifier-resolution=node --loader ts-node/esm src/app.ts`

this is the output:

```
(node:10073) ExperimentalWarning: --experimental-loader is an experimental feature. This feature could change at any time
(Use `node --trace-warnings ...` to show where the warning was created)
(node:10073) ExperimentalWarning: The Node.js specifier resolution flag is experimental. It could change or be removed at any time.
running on port 3000.
```

whenever i use it i get the expected results.

now i tried to dockerize the whole thing, but docker exits (0) whenever i start the container, right after the first 3 log lines (same as running them locally):
[image: docker log output]

The dockerfile looks like that:

```
FROM node:16-alpine3.17
WORKDIR /usr/src/app
COPY package*.json ./

RUN npm install
# If you are building your code for production
# RUN npm ci --only=production

COPY . .
EXPOSE 3000

CMD [ "node", "--experimental-specifier-resolution=node", "--loader", "ts-node/esm src/app.ts" ]
```

shouldnt it keep running? Why does it exit immidiately?

Thank you so much for any idea!

Answer (score 0):

Answer to myself:

the last line in the Dockerfile is wrong. it needs to be like so (splitted into seperate "xx"):

```
CMD [ "node","--experimental-specifier-resolution", "node", "--loader", "ts-node/esm", "src/app.ts" ]
```

Cheers